# Can a CCSprite switch between multiple animations?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, ccaction

Is it possible to make a CCSprite switch between two different animations? (both are CCRepeatForever)

I try to use stopAction: and runAction: but it crashes the app.
I can only use pauseSchedulerAndActions: and resumeSchedulerAndActions: with one animation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes. If switching animations troubles you, use one sprite for each animation and keep them all updated to the same position, and only set the one to visible whose animation should be played.

The crash is certainly unrelated.